# Documenting constants with Doxygen in C

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

I have various groups of constants in a C .h file that I'd like to document with Doxygen.

Example: axis, direction, possible values.

```
#define TYPE_LAT 0x01
#define TYPE_LONG 0x02

#define NORTH 0x01
#define SOUTH 0x02
#define EAST 0x01
#define WEST 0x02

#define TROPIC_OF_CANCER 23.5
#define EQUATOR 0
#define PRIME_MERIDIAN 0
#define SYD_LAT_DIR SOUTH
#define SYD_LNG_DIR EAST
#define SYD_LAT_VAL 151.21
#define SYD_LNG_VAL 33.9
```

These would be arguments for parameters in a function like:

```
void SetOneDimension(int axis, int direction, float value);
```

and for Sydney I'd do:

```
SetOneDimension(TYPE_LAT, SYD_LAT_DIR, SYD_LAT_VAL);
SetOneDimension(TYPE_LNG, SYD_LNG_DIR, SYD_LNG_VAL);
```

Ideally in the documentation I'd like to categorise the constants where I show them as sub-sections to their appropriate "parents," like this:

```
Dimension types:

#define TYPE_LAT 0x01
    Directions:
    #define NORTH 0x01
    #define SOUTH 0x02
    #define SYD_LAT_DIR SOUTH
        Key Values:
        #define EQUATOR 0
        #define TROPIC_OF_CANCER 23.5
        #define SYD_LAT_VAL 151.21


#define TYPE_LAT 0x02
    Directions:
    #define EAST 0x01
    #define WEST 0x02
    #define SYD_LNG_DIR EAST   
        Key Values:
        #define PRIME_MERIDIAN 0
        #define SYD_LNG_VAL 33.9
```

with a relevant comment for each. This allows a quick sighting for valid sets / combinations of parameters. The example above is simple - I would actually have functions with multiple commands, sub-commands and possible values.

Doxygen member groups would be great but I don't think they allow sub-groups like I am after. There is the possibility of using module groups but I htink these go beyond what I'm after here.

Do you have any suggestions on how to document these with Doxygen?

Comment: W version of doxygen are you using? You wrote: "Doxygen member groups would be great but I don't think they allow sub-groups" why do you think this, what did you try (show what you tried). Groups can be nested. Maybe you should have also have a look at the `\name` command.